# angularjs form textbox validation: Enter nine digits or leave it empty

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I got a requirement to validate a textbox, when the user chooses to enter Tax Id Number, they have to enter 9 digit otherwise leave the textbox empty upon which the form is valid and a submit button is enabled. I am trying to do it this way. but this is not working. Please let me know better ways to do this.

```
   <form name ="tinForm">
        <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text"
                     ng-model="person.tin"
                     name="tin"
                     ng-minlength="9"
                     maxlength="9"/>
                 <span class="help-block" ng-show="tinForm.tin.$invalid"> Please enter 9 digits </span>
             </div>
          </form>

       <div>
           <button ng-disabled="!tinForm.person.tin.$valid">Submit</button>
        </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: the answer by @dalorzo is good, but you might also be able to use ng-pattern as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check it using ng-pattern

```
<form name="myform">
   <input type="text" name="myfield" ng-model="abcd" ng-pattern="/^$|^[0-9X]{10}$/"> 
   <span>valid : {{myform.myfield.$valid}}</span>
</form>
```

checkout this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xv81puxRws4t44CiatOF?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using `ngBlur`:

```
<input type="text" ng-blur="testLength()"
                     ng-model="person.tin"
                     name="tin"
                     ng-minlength="9"
                     maxlength="9"/>
```

On your controller:

```
$scope.testLength=function(){ 
  if (person.tin.length <9)
     person.tin = "";
}
```